# resultset.next() is showing output of first row only

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

So, I have something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter owner's IC no. or plate no. : ");
String update = in.nextLine();

String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM `vehicle` WHERE ic='%s' OR plate ='%s'",update,update);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("RegNo." +"\t\t"+ "Name" + "\t\t" + "IC" +"\t\t" + "Plate No." + "\t" + "Color" + "\t\t" + "Year" + "\t\t" + "Make" + "\t\t" + "Model" +"\t\t"+ "Capacity" + "\t" + "Type" +"\t\t" + "Max Load");
}
else {
    System.out.println("IC and PLate No. not found....");}

while (rs.next()) {
    regno = rs.getInt("regno");
    name = rs.getString("name");
    ic = rs.getString("ic");
    plate = rs.getString("plate");
    color = rs.getString("color");
    year = rs.getInt("year");
    make = rs.getString("make");
    model = rs.getString("model");
    capacity = rs.getDouble("capacity");
    type = rs.getString("type");
    maxload = rs.getDouble("maxload");

    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, if data is found in the database, it will then print the following table for outputs that match.

Now, It is supposed to print out every output. But, it only prints out the first one.

I believe that the following code is the cause:

```
 if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("RegNo." +"\t\t"+ "Name" + "\t\t" + "IC" +"\t\t" + "Plate No." + "\t" + "Color" + "\t\t" + "Year" + "\t\t" + "Make" + "\t\t" + "Model" +"\t\t"+ "Capacity" + "\t" + "Type" +"\t\t" + "Max Load");
}
else {
    System.out.println("IC and PLate No. not found....");}
```

Comment: How are your two code snippets related?  Does one call the other?

Comment: They are in the same method

Comment: We need more context, then.  Your `while` loop should loop the cursor through the entire ResultSet.  And your `if` statement *also* moves the cursor forward one row.  Both of them modify the cursor's position in the ResultSet, so we need to know what the full flow of data is.  Can you edit your post to include enough code for others to replicate your problem?

Comment: Ok, I have did some editing

Comment: The code as shown will **skip** the first row, not show only the first row... Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: you should **not** `String.format` values into a query string, you should use prepared statements with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MessageFormat` to format the output, and the `counter` to determine if empty result set, like so:

```
String strFormat = "RegNo. {0}\tName {1}\tIC {2}\tPlate No. {3}\tColor {4}\tYear {5}\tMake {6}\tModel {7}\tCapacity {8}\tType {9}\tMax Load {10}");

int counter = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    counter++;

    regno = rs.getInt("regno");
    name = rs.getString("name");
    ic = rs.getString("ic");
    plate = rs.getString("plate");
    color = rs.getString("color");
    year = rs.getInt("year");
    make = rs.getString("make");
    model = rs.getString("model");
    capacity = rs.getDouble("capacity");
    type = rs.getString("type");
    maxload = rs.getDouble("maxload");

    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(strFormat, regno, name, ic, plate, color, year, make, model, capacity, type, maxload));
}

if (counter == 0) {
    System.out.println("IC and PLate No. not found....");
}
```

Comment: Yea, It is an alternative way to do so. Thanks.

Comment: But the output is kinda messy, How can the alignment be done if I am using this way.

Comment: Please use `\t` for tabs and `\n` for line breaks

Comment: @TaiShengHong It's not an 'alternate way to do so'. It is a *correct* way to do so, unlike your own code. There are other alternatives, but your code isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, when used select query with Prepared statement.
For example-

```
String sqlquerySELECTAgentsWithParam = " select * from AGENTS WHERE AGENT_CODE = ( ? ) ";
```

it returned a single row, since I've used IF condition and then `while(rs.next())`
I couldn't print the single row, Hence, I've used do-while loop like below in order to print the first-row result. code snippet below- hope it will help !!

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracelDBUrl, oracleDBUser,oracleDBPwd );

if (conn != null) { System.out.println("Connected to the Oracle DB ");  }
else { System.out.println("Failed to Connect to Oracle DB "); }
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlquerySELECTAgentsWithParam);
pstmt.setString(1,"<agent_id>");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
boolean returnResultrs = rs.next();
System.out.println("Fetched Result is = " +returnResultrs);
if(returnResultrs)
{
    do {
        System.out.println("Inside Do - While Loop");
        System.out.println("AGENT_CODE = " + rs.getString(1)+ "has AGENT_NAME = "  +rs.getString(2));
        }
while(rs.next());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see two issues here.  The biggest one is this:

```
System.out.println(toString());
```

That calls the `.toString()` method on the current class, which will *not* output any of the data from your `ResultSet`.  At least, not based on any of the code you've shown.  You're storing all of the values coming back from the `ResultSet` in variables, but those variables don't appear to be getting used anywhere.  You need to get those variables to your `.println()` somehow.

The second issue is that `rs.next()` moves the cursor forward one row.  So when you do this:

```
if(rs.next()) {
```

That causes you to skip the first row.  This is actually kind of tricky to fix, because there's no good way to tell whether or not a `ResultSet` is empty without calling `.next()`.  The way I'd probably handle this is to pull all of the results into objects in a list, and then do all the printing based on the list, and not on the `ResultSet` itself.

Comment: That problem with `next()` can be fixed by using a `do .. while` instead of a `while` **inside** the if-branch. There is no need to pull the entire result set to avoid that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, good call.  I'm so used to using `ResultSetExtractor` that the simpler solution didn't even occur to me!